# Secure login on wordpress

Tags: login

I want to create a login page on wordpress where users type in there username and password and are the redirected to a page that is specified to the user only like for example if u login to facebook or bid or buy. I want to be able to let the users login to a page where they can find files that are only available for the specific user. Almost like E-learning.

Comment: WordPress might not be the best option for that.  Consider exploring Moodle or another platform designed for the project.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a function like wp_get_current_user() or get_currentuserinfo() on the page they land on once logged in (via wp-login.php) it will provide you information on the user that just logged in, like ID and username etc. You can use this information to bring in that specific users details/posts/auction items/courses/whatever with a custom query or otherwise.

It's not an exact implementation but it's a start. There's too many more questions around how you are gathering/storing the information specific to that specific to that user, or what information is stored, or how users create new content in the first place in order to give you an exact answer.

Here's a reference to start on: http://codex.wordpress.org/get_currentuserinfo

Hope that helps.